# Where is my one more edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

At the [Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) I selects `editors` and sets filter option to `all`. Now I can see my edits count (this indicates that I have **68** edits.)

[image]

But today I suddenly opened [Suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/125238) page and was surprised when I had saw this info:
[image]

So, 71-2 = **69**. I think than either something is wrong or I don't understand some rules in edit system. Explain please, where is my another edit?

Comment: Lost in the cache?

Comment: That's the number of suggestions approved, you don't lose on total edits if your suggestion is rejected, you simply don't get incremented. So you've *made* 72 (now, at least) *successful* edits, but 74 attempts in total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely it's just caching. The editors page may only update once a day, and your last edit was approved only four hours ago.

Comment: This is the right answer: The editors page is not immediately updated when a new edit is done. Between the two pages, the editors page is the one you can trust less.

Comment: I don't think this is it. It's incremented to 69 now, but another suggested edit was made. Were it a caching issue, then the update shouldn't have carried the "inconsistency", though as mentioned the inconsistency is actually on a count of 3, not simply 1.

Answer (score 3):

You may have also edited posts that for one reason or another got deleted.  They would still show up on your accepted suggested edits count, but would be gone from your main count of edits.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is the case, since the difference is actually 3. And, while the post that was edited may have ceased to be, the fact you submitted an edit suggestion remains. The edit count, however, goes by the number of live edits.